# Two-way foreign key constraint check

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I have these two tables:

```
Table player
+----+----------+------------+
| ID | Nickname | Lastloc_ID |
+----+----------+------------+

Table location
+----+---+---+---+
| ID | X | Y | Z |
+----+---+---+---+
```

I want to connect `player.Lastloc_ID` with `location.ID` so that:

- When I *update* `player.Lastloc_ID` with new value, corresponding old row in `location` gets deleted.
- When I *delete* row in `player`, corresponding row in `location` gets deleted.
- When I *update* `location` with new coordinates, nothing happens.
- When I *delete* row in `location`, `player.Lastloc_ID` changes to NULL.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

**Important note**:
Table `location` is general table which holds locations. There can be more tables which uses this table to store locations (each table creating its new record, always 1:1 relationship).

Answer (score 0):

May be [ON DELETE CASCADE](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/) is what you need.